# USB devices need replugging after reboot

Tags: wifi, usb, hardware, mouse, reboot

Two of my USB devices don't work after rebooting my PC: my mouse and the external WiFi adapter.

Other USB devices like printer, keyboard or external disks all work fine. Mouse and Wifi, however, always have to be disconnected/reconnected - then they work as expected. Everything also works fine when I remove the power cord completely and then power on the machine. Normal shutdown doesn't work.

I looked around and found different suggestions, such as resetting the USB port, for which I used this [usbreset](https://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=121459435621262&w=2) utility , which works for my mouse, although it takes some time (10 seconds), while an unplug/plug of the mouse cord works instantly.

Switching USB ports doesn't make any difference, I tried different USB ports, even the old USB 2.0 ports.

It doesn't work for my WiFi adapter though. I also found it isn't even listed when executing [lsusb](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB) . Is there any solution that works for both devices?

System info:

- Kernel 5.5.15-1
- Distribution: Manjaro
- Desktop Environment: KDE Plasma 5.18.4
- Mainboard: [ASRock B450M Pro4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M%20Pro4/) and its [manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B450M%20Pro4.pdf)

usb section of dmesg output looks like this:

```
[    8.543260] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[    8.621357] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    8.621359] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    8.625461] input: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:38:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:045E:07F8.0001/input/input15
[    8.680636] hid-generic 0003:045E:07F8.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:38:00.3-4/input0
[    8.680937] input: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:38:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.1/0003:045E:07F8.0002/input/input16
[    8.740196] input: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:38:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.1/0003:045E:07F8.0002/input/input17
[    8.740301] hid-generic 0003:045E:07F8.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:38:00.3-4/input1
[    8.950935] fuse: init (API version 7.31)
[    8.950991] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[    8.950994] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[   10.563896] kauditd_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
[   10.563897] audit: type=1130 audit(1586452184.476:45): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=rtkit-daemon comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   11.163360] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 2
[   12.340958] audit: type=1130 audit(1586452186.252:46): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-wait-online comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   12.344467] audit: type=1130 audit(1586452186.256:47): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=expressvpn comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   12.530392] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452186.439:48): table=filter family=2 entries=0
[   12.562109] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452186.472:49): table=filter family=10 entries=0
[   12.774046] aufs 5.5-20200302
[   13.135884] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   13.139005] Bridge firewalling registered
[   13.166492] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452187.076:50): table=nat family=2 entries=0
[   13.201972] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452187.112:51): table=nat family=2 entries=5
[   13.204115] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452187.116:52): table=filter family=2 entries=4
[   13.206234] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452187.116:53): table=filter family=2 entries=6
[   13.208873] audit: type=1325 audit(1586452187.119:54): table=filter family=2 entries=8
[   13.238387] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   13.546480] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   13.676962] ahci 0000:15:00.1: port does not support device sleep
[   13.756687] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[   14.153438] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   15.977783] kauditd_printk_skb: 37 callbacks suppressed
[   15.977785] audit: type=1131 audit(1586452189.889:92): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   18.949402] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   23.952635] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   24.160012] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[   24.160068] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[   24.803571] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   30.016938] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   36.163628] audit: type=1131 audit(1586452210.076:93): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   41.350165] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   41.610038] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   42.040881] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a070, bcdDevice= 1.04
[   42.040885] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   42.040887] usb 1-5: Product: USB Gaming Mouse
[   42.040889] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Sun Sonny
[   42.956688] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   43.014384] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271, bcdDevice= 1.08
[   43.014389] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[   43.014391] usb 1-6: Product: UB91C
[   43.014393] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[   43.014395] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 12345
[   43.038423] usb 1-6: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[   43.620567] input: Sun Sonny USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:15:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:04D9:A070.0006/input/input18
[   43.677091] holtek_mouse 0003:04D9:A070.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sun Sonny USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:15:00.0-5/input0
[   43.677572] input: Sun Sonny USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:15:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:04D9:A070.0007/input/input19
[   43.733544] holtek_mouse 0003:04D9:A070.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Sun Sonny USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:15:00.0-5/input1
[   43.733755] holtek_mouse 0003:04D9:A070.0008: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Sun Sonny USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:15:00.0-5/input2
[   44.118540] usb 1-6: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[   44.367951] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[   44.382279] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[   44.594532] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[   44.594535] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[   44.594537] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[   44.594538] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   44.594539] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   44.594541] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   44.594542] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[   44.594543] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   44.598475] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
[   44.611638] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0 wlp21s0f0u6: renamed from wlan0
[   44.613348] audit: type=1130 audit(1586452218.522:94): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Comment: What's the color of the USB sockets on the motherboard you connect those peripherals to? Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I guess with color of USB sockets you mean USB 2/3? I added this and other information to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I added the the mainboard info, I tried all busses, so the ports where black, blue or blue/black.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular Wi-Fi bug that got introduced in kernel 5.5.1.

It's verified fixed in kernel 5.6.2 but was definitely **NOT** fixed in 5.5.14.

Speculation was that the fix would make it into 5.5.15 but I've not seen confirmation of that.

Here is the [Bugtraq](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206395).

Comment: It's listed in the changelog: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.5.15 Unfortunately, it is not the problem I an having.